# numpy multiplication: can not broadcast

Tags: numpy

This is probably a very dumb question, but I have been stuck for 45 mins

```
np.multiply(np.transpose(phi), phi)
```

phi is a matrix, I am getting:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,10) (10,4)
```

I mean, isnt matrix multiplication valid for shapes (n,m) (m,p)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.multiply`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) is *element-wise* multiplication.  Use the function `np.dot` or the `dot` method for matrix multiplication.  If `phi` is a [`np.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html#matrix-objects) instance, you can also use the binary operator `*`, e.g. `phi.T * phi`.

For example, `a` is a numpy array (but not an instance of `np.matrix`):

```
In [7]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])

In [8]: a.T.dot(a)
Out[8]: 
array([[35, 44],
       [44, 56]])
```

Create a `np.matrix` instance from `a`:

```
In [9]: m = np.matrix(a)

In [10]: m
Out[10]: 
matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]])

In [11]: m.T.dot(m)
Out[11]: 
matrix([[35, 44],
        [44, 56]])

In [12]: m.T * m
Out[12]: 
matrix([[35, 44],
        [44, 56]])
```

Comment: `*` will work if `phi` is an instance of `np.matrix`.  I added some sample code: note that `a` (created using `np.array()`) is an `np.ndarray` instance, and `m` is a `np.matrix` instance.

Answer (score 0):

This works as you anticipate:

```
np.dot(phi.T,phi)
```

As explained by @Warren Weckesser, `np.muliply` (or the `*` operator) perform element wise operations on numpy **arrays**.

The `*` operator performs matrix muliplications for numpy **matrices**

See [this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935) useful article for the difference between the numpy arrays and matrices. It recommends that you use arrays.